# [Storm][DRPC] Request failed

Tags: cluster-computing, apache-storm, topology, drpc

We work with storm and use the DRPC to execute some algorithms on the cluster.

When the duration time on each node is less than 60 seconds, there is no trouble: client receives correct result. However when we have to solve bigger problem with the same algorithm (then duration time is more than 60 seconds) we have the following message:

```
Exception in thread "main" DRPCExecutionException(msg:Request failed) at
backtype.storm.generated.DistributedRPC$execute_result$execute_resultStandardScheme.read(DistributedRPC.java:1222) at 
backtype.storm.generated.DistributedRPC$execute_result$execute_resultStandardScheme.read(DistributedRPC.java:1200) at backtype.storm.generated...
```

It seems to be about the node, which sends a message to cluster with "Request failed" and doesn't finish algorithm. 
Hope somebody have a hint to solve this :(

Note that the Client-DRPC-Topology and the 10 test nodes work properly when the duration is less than the minute.

Thank you.

Comment: does the request times out or the topology is explicitly calling invoking request fail? You can check it in the drpc server logs.

Comment: The topology invokes "Request fail" (Rf). In fact Node sends "Rf" to cluster and the DRPC server send it to Client.
Sometime, it take less than 60 seconds (about 50 seconds).

So, we are in some trouble...

Comment: did you get solution for this problem ?