# Storm-hbase bolt failing over DRPC

Tags: hbase, apache-storm

I am writing a Storm topology to read data from HBase using DRPC. Essentially this performs a scan to get data, enriches the data and returns it.

I can easily get a basic DRPC example working (based on http://storm.apache.org/releases/current/Distributed-RPC.html). However when I insert the code for the scan, the process takes a very long time. After a minute, I get the following error:

backtype.storm.generated.DRPCExecutionException

at backtype.storm.daemon.drpc$service_handler$reify__8688.failRequest(drpc.clj:136) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.2.4.2.0-258.jar:0.10.0.2.4.2.0-258]

at backtype.storm.drpc.DRPCSpout.fail(DRPCSpout.java:241) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.2.4.2.0-258.jar:0.10.0.2.4.2.0-258

A short while later, I get org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException. This doesn't always happen, but is very common. My assumption based on this is one of two possibilities:

The scan is timing out. However performing the scan through HBase Shell or REST return in less than a second
The table is inconsistent, causing a certain region to be missing. I have run hbase hbck and it shows 0 inconsistencies.
I know that the connection to HBase is fine: I have added debugging output and the bolt gets the results. However due to the DRPCExecutionException, these results are never returned over DRPC.

I though the issue was DRPC timeout, however I have increased the DRPC timeout a lot and I get the same result in the same amount of time. After Googling I found someone else with the same issue ([[Storm][DRPC] Request failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940623/stormdrpc-request-failed)) but there is no indication of how to fix this.

For reference I am adding my code below:

```
try (Table table = HbaseClient.connection().getTable(TableName.valueOf("EPG_URI"))) 
    {
        List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
        String startRowString = "start";
        String endRowString = "end";
        RowFilter startRow = new RowFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.GREATER_OR_EQUAL, new BinaryPrefixComparator(startRowString.getBytes()));
        filters.add(startRow);
        RowFilter endRow = new RowFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.LESS_OR_EQUAL, new BinaryPrefixComparator(endRowString.getBytes()));
        filters.add(endRow);
        FilterList filterList = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL, filters);

        Scan scan = new Scan();
        scan.addFamily("f1".getBytes());
        scan.setFilter(filterList);

        ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan);
        for (Result result : scanner) 
        {
            hbaseValues.add(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I don't know why the initial problem occurred, but I did fix it by heavily simplifying my scanner:

```
Scan scan = new Scan(startRowString.getBytes(), endRowString.getBytes());
scan.addFamily("f1".getBytes());
ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan);            
for (Result r : scanner)
{...}
```

Based on this, the problem seems to be on the HBase side rather than Storm.